# What type of spellcasting bonus do I use as a multiclassed bard/cleric?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, multi-classing, bard, spellcasting

I'm fairly new to D&D, and I'm going to multiclass for the first time - Bard/Cleric, to be specific.

What kind of spellcasting bonus do I use for spells like Healing Word which is bard *and* cleric? Do I have to choose between 1d4+Wis and 1d4+Cha?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Have you read the multiclassing rules on spellcasting?

Comment: Vlad, please review the questions I've marked as a duplicate of this one to see if they answer your question. (Fundamentally, the question and answer is the same regardless of which spellcasting classes you're multiclassed between.) If that still doesn't answer your question, please edit your question to clarify what you're confused about. Let me know if you have any other questions about the site!